# Can't switch to all users in WIN 8 - search extended user control

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts, user

I'm using Windows 8 (not PRO) and I created different users (as local or MS user). But in the "normal" user control center (e.g. control nusrmgr.cpl) I get only two users.

I found one day a page which provides the name of a extended user control which was started by command line. It brings up the "old" win 7 control center which provides more functionality and list all users.

But I forget this special command and could not find it again.

Does anyone know how start this extended user control in WIN8 or how to switch to a user which is hidden in the normal user control.

Thanks
Thorsten